# Does allocating using sizeof yield wrong size for structure pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

Using valgrind to read this I get: Invalid write/read of size 4

```
 struct Person{
        char* name;
        int age;
    };

    struct Person* create_person(char *name, int age)
    {
        struct Person* me = (struct Person*)malloc(sizeof(struct Person*));
        assert(me!= NULL); //make sure that the statement is not null
        me->name = name;
        me->age = age;

        return me;
    }
```

Using this got clean log with valgrind

```
struct Person{
    char* name;
    int age;
};

struct Person* create_person(char *name, int age)
{
    struct Person* me = (struct Person*)malloc(sizeof(struct Person*)+4);
    assert(me!= NULL); //make sure that the statement is not null
    me->name = name;
    me->age = age;

    return me;
}
```

Why should I explicitly put `sizeof(struct+intSize)` to avoid this error? `sizeof` don't get the whole size of a struct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong size in the call to `malloc`.

```
struct Person* me = (struct Person*)malloc(sizeof(struct Person*));
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That is a size of a pointer, not the size of an object. You need to use:

```
struct Person* me = (struct Person*)malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
```

To avoid errors like this, use the following pattern and don't cast the return value of `malloc` (See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)):

```
struct Person* me = malloc(sizeof(*me));
```

It's a coincidence that `malloc(sizeof(struct Person*)+4)` works. Your `struct` has a pointer and an `int`. It appears `sizeof(int)` on your platform is 4. Hence, `sizeof(struct Person*)+4` happen to match the size of `struct Person`.

Comment: Ty. I got this 4 from valgrind output. ;P

Comment: Note: Could even use `malloc(sizeof *me)`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to allocate enough space to hold *an entire structure*, not just a pointer to it.

That is, use `sizeof(struct Person)` and not `sizeof(struct Person*)`.

`sizeof(struct Person*)+4` is *coincidentally* big enough on your platform.